# Executar ações a partir do item selecionado no JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Eu queria atribuir valor a uma outra classe, conforme o que estiver selecionado no `JComboBox`. Por exemplo, se o item "Ativo" de um combo estiver selecionado eu queria atribuir um valor para uma string de uma classe externa, se o usuário tivesse colocado o item do combo "Inativo" idem. Como eu faço para saber qual dos dois itens estão selecionados?

OBS : Adote o nome `cmbStatus` como nome do `JComboBox`, onde existem apenas dois itens : "Ativo" e "Inativo"

Comment: Você quer fazer algo quando uma opção do jcombobox for selecionada?

Comment: Sim ! Quero atribuir um valor a uma variável de acordo com os itens do combo

Comment: Trecho de código?! Você já fez alguma coisa?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta efetuar a ação desejada dentro do método [`itemStateChanged`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html#itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent)):

```
seuJCombo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                // 
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    //ação aqui
                }
            }
       });
```

Basicamente você está criando um `listener` que ficará monitorando alterações de seleção no `JComboBox`, e quando houver alguma alteração, o `if` checa se o status do item é "selecionado".

Uma vez confirmado que o item foi o selecionado, basta tratar a opção selecionada usando [`e.getItem()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#getItem--):

```
seuJCombo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                // 
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    //pegando o texto do item selecionado
                    String valorSelecionado = e.getItem().toString();
                    if(valorSelecionado.equals("ativo")){
                        //altere aqui quando ativo selecionado
                  }else{
                   //altere aqui quando inativo selecionado
                }
            }
        });
```

> **Obs.:** `e.getItem()` retorna um tipo `Object`, então, é necessário efetuar o `cast` para o tipo esperado no `JComboBox`, no caso do
>   exemplo, espera-se apenas o texto da opção selecionada, então foi
>   feito o `cast` para `String`.

Comment: Obrigado cara ! Mas assim, eu não entendi onde eu tenho que colocar o item do meu combo '-'

Comment: @DanielSantos veja se a edição te responde.

Comment: Seria interessante o downvote me informar o que tem de errado na questão, para que eu possa corrigir, pois não consegui notar nenhum erro.

Comment: Valeu mesmo cara ! Agora eu entendi !