# Pegar valor selecionado do JComboBox populado com Enum

Tags: java, swing

Eu tenho na minha janela um `JComboBox` com itens de um enum, e um `JLabel` para mostrar o valor do item selecionado no combo.

Até ai tudo bem, estou conseguindo fazer isso, só que estou meio inseguro se estou fazendo do jeito certo, pois não sei se existe uma maneira mais eficiente de fazer isso.

Evento do JComboBox :

```
form.cmbPizza.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(form.cmbPizza.getSelectedItem() != null){
                    if(Pizzas.CALABRESA == (Pizzas) form.cmbPizza.getSelectedItem()){
                        form.lblPrecoPizza.setText("R$ " + Pizzas.CALABRESA.preco);
                    }
                }else{
                    form.lblPrecoPizza.setText("R$ 0,00");
                }
            }
        });
```

Enum :

```
        public enum Pizzas {

            CALABRESA("25,99"), MUSSARELA("25,99"), PALMITO("19,99"), PORTUGUESA("19,99"),
 CATUPIRY("25,99"), PROVOLONE("19,99"), LOMBO("29,99");

            public String preco;

            private Pizzas(String s) {
                preco = s; 
            }

        }
```

A questão é que eu tenho vários itens no enum, dai surge minha dúvida, vou ter que fazer isso que eu acabei de fazer com todos os itens ou existe uma forma menos complicada e mais eficiente de fazer isso?

Comment: Não é duplicata dessa? [Executar ações a partir do item selecionado no JComboBox](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117900/28595)

Comment: Ah verdade ! É que como a pergunta é outra, achei que não teria a resposta que eu queria... Vlw !

Comment: Você quer uma maneira generica de exibir o `Enum` sem ter que fazer switch é isso né? Se sim, não é duplicata.

Comment: Exatamente, estava tentando mudar meu código com algumas coisas que você colocou na outra pergunta, mas não consegui kkk

Comment: Adicione seu enum na pergunta, estou pra responder mas sem ver seu enum talvez a resposta não atenda.

Comment: Pra fazer o que eu quero, usarei um ActionListener ou ItemListener ?

Comment: Veja a resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro adicione no seu `Enum` um método que retorne o *preço* da opção:

```
public enum Pizzas {

    CALABRESA("25,99"), MUSSARELA("25,99"), PALMITO("19,99"), PORTUGUESA("19,99"),
    CATUPIRY("25,99"), PROVOLONE("19,99"), LOMBO("29,99");

    public String preco;

    private Pizzas(String s) {
        preco = s;
    }
    public String getValue(){
        return preco;
    }
}
```

Conforme já respondi na [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117903/28595), basta adaptar o código de lá para seu `Enum`. E para monitorar alterações de seleção de `JComboBox`, deve-se usar `ItemStateChanged`:

```
form.cmbPizza.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

             if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                Pizzas p = (Pizzas) e.getItem();
                 jLabel1.setText("R$" + p.getValue());
            }
        });
```

Veja funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @DanielSantos sim, esqueci de trocar na hora de colar aqui.

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, vc está pegando o nome do item selecionado e comparando se há algum nome igual na lista de enum, é isso ?

Comment: Na verdade, os objetos enum já estão todos carregados no combobox, o que o código faz é pegar o item selecionado e chamando o método que trará o valor carregado em `preco`.