# NumberFormatException em GUI

Tags: java, swing, gui

Tenho um programa que simula um sistema de uma pizzaria, onde os preços dos produtos estão armazenados em enums como double. Os `JLabel` da janela pegam esses valores dos preços e apresentam ela na tela dessa forma : `"R$ "+ p.getValue;`. Onde o `p.getValue` é o preço. Eu peguei essa String e coloquei dentro de uma variável double (usando o `.substring(3);`). Eu efetuo a soma dessas variáveis e "jogo" pra dentro do texto de um `JTextField`, até ai tudo ocorreu normal, só que quando eu aplico um `DecimalFormat` para mostrar duas casas decimais(`df.applyPattern(##.##))`, e executo, ele aplica esse padrão, só que no console aparece "NumberFormatException: For input String :"37,49".

Método onde eu pego o preço (`.getValue`) do item do enum (double), conforme faço alteração de item num `JComboBox`:

```
form.cmbPizza.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {  
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    Pizzas p = (Pizzas) e.getItem();
                    form.lblPrecoPizza.setText("R$ "+p.getValue());
                }else{
                    form.lblPrecoPizza.setText("R$ 0.00");
                }
            }
        });
```

Método que realiza as formatações e conversões :

```
form.btnCalcular.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Apresentar soma dos produtos

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            form.precoPizza = Double.parseDouble(form.lblPrecoPizza.getText().substring(3));
            form.precoSuco = Double.parseDouble(form.lblPrecoSuco.getText().substring(3));
            form.precoRefri = Double.parseDouble(form.lblPrecoRefri.getText().substring(3));

            df.applyPattern("##.##");
            form.txtPrecoTotal.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(form.precoPizza + form.precoSuco + form.precoRefri)));
            double x = Double.parseDouble(form.txtPrecoTotal.getText()); //Linha onde é acusado o erro
            df.format(x);
            if(form.chkVip.isSelected()){
                double desconto = (form.precoPizza + form.precoRefri + form.precoSuco)*0.15;
                form.txtPrecoTotal.setText(df.format(String.valueOf(form.precoPizza + form.precoSuco + form.precoRefri - desconto)));
            }

        }
    });
```

Deixando claro, mais uma vez que se trata de um erro de RunTime, e não de compilação e que, o erro não ocorre somente com esse valor, mas sim, com qualquer valor !

Comment: De onde vem essa vírgula entre o 37 e o 49? Números em inglês são separados por ponto.

Comment: Adicione o stacktrace completo, mostrando onde exatamente está estourando essa exceção. Mas já te adianto que se você estiver usando os valores do `ENUM` conforme o código [dessa sua outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121292/28595), o problema pode está nessas vírgulas, separador de double e float é ponto(.). Experimente fazer a troca direto no ENUM para ver se o erro persiste.

Comment: Então cara, meu programa não tem nenhum número com vírgula, apenas ponto, meu professor disse que no console o número aparece com vírgula por que a IDE na hora que vai lançar o erro, ela vê qual o padrão de separação do seu país e aplica eles no seu número ...

Comment: Daniel, tem sim, no seu ENUM os números estão com vírgula, pelo menos no código que você postou na outra pergunta. Quando você faz `p.getValue()`, vem os valores do ENUM do jeito que está declarado, ou seja, com vírgula. Tente fazer como eu disse, altere no ENUM as vírgulas por ponto nos preços e veja se o erro persiste.

Comment: Diego, os enums já estão alterados com ponto, substitui todas as vírgulas que existiam no código, e continua dando o mesmo erro

Comment: Então adicione na pergunta a pilha de erros  que aparecem no console, não dá pra adivinhar a origem do erro sem ver a mensagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel, para tratar os valores, ao invés de usar o R$ *hardcode*, você pode usar a classe [`NumberFormat`](http://blog.caelum.com.br/internacionalizacao-no-codigo-java/), usando um método utilitário como:

```
// Adicione esses atributos à sua classe
private Locale localeBrasil = new Locale("pt", "BR");
private NumberFormat formatoMonetario = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(localeBrasil);

// Método utilitário
public double parseValor(String str) {
    Number valor = 0;

    try {
        valor = formatoMonetario.parse(str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }

    return valor.doubleValue();
}
```

Substituindo onde você recupera o valor:

```
form.precoPizza = Double.parseDouble(form.lblPrecoPizza.getText().substring(3));
```

Por:

```
form.precoPizza = parseValor(form.lblPrecoPizza.getText());
```

---

E onde você seta o valor:

```
form.lblPrecoPizza.setText("R$ "+ p.getValue());
```

por:

```
form.lblPrecoPizza.setText(formatoMonetario.format(p.getValue()));
```

Ficando algo assim:

```
form.cmbPizza.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {  
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    Pizzas p = (Pizzas) e.getItem();
                    form.lblPrecoPizza.setText(formatoMonetario.format(p.getValue()));
                }else{
                    form.lblPrecoPizza.setText(formatoMonetario.format(0));
                }
            }
        });


form.btnCalcular.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Apresentar soma dos produtos

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            form.precoPizza = parseValor(form.lblPrecoPizza.getText());
            form.precoSuco = parseValor(form.lblPrecoSuco.getText());
            form.precoRefri = parseValor(form.lblPrecoRefri.getText());

            form.txtPrecoTotal.setText(formatoMonetario.format(form.precoPizza + form.precoSuco + form.precoRefri));
            double x = parseValor(form.txtPrecoTotal.getText());

            if(form.chkVip.isSelected()){
                double desconto = (form.precoPizza + form.precoRefri + form.precoSuco)*0.15;
                form.txtPrecoTotal.setText(formatoMonetario.format(form.precoPizza + form.precoSuco + form.precoRefri - desconto));
            }
        }
    });
```

Abcs!