# Exibir dados de objeto do JCombobox em um JTextArea a partir do item selecionado

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jtextarea

Eu queria mostrar os dados de um cliente que está em um combobox dentro de uma JTextArea, como na imagem à seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que só é mostrada a informação do "Igo Brasil", quando tento mostrar as informaçoes de outro cliente, ocorre isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As informações do primeiro cliente persistem no JTextArea.

Meu código que faz essa listagem é o seguinte:

```
    cli = (Cliente) this.cbcliente.getSelectedItem();
    txtareacliente.setText("Cliente: " +cli.getCliNome()+
                           "\n\nCPF: " +cli.getCliCpf()+
                           "\n\nRG: " +cli.getCliRg()+
                           "\n\nSexo: " +cli.getCliSexo());
```

E o ClienteDAO é:

```
package model.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import model.bean.Cliente;
import model.connection.ConnectionFactory;


public class ClienteDao {

 Connection con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();;
 String sql;
 PreparedStatement pstm;
 ResultSet rs;

 public void salvarCliente(Cliente cli) {

  try {

   sql = "INSERT INTO cliente(clinome,clicpf,clirg,clisexo,clifone)" + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);";

   pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
   pstm.setString(1, cli.getCliNome());
   pstm.setString(2, cli.getCliCpf());
   pstm.setString(3, cli.getCliRg());
   pstm.setString(4, cli.getCliSexo());
   pstm.setString(5, cli.getCliFone());
   // Para Insert, Delete e Update usa-se: pstm.execute(). 
   // Para Select, usa-se: pstm.executeQuery();
   pstm.execute();

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados inseridos com sucesso");

  } catch (Exception erro) {

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao salvar " + erro.getMessage());


  }
 }

 public List < Cliente > listarClientes() {

  List < Cliente > lista = new ArrayList < > ();

  try {

   sql = "SELECT clicodigo,clinome,clicpf,clirg,clifone,clisexo FROM cliente ORDER BY clicodigo;";

   pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
   rs = pstm.executeQuery(sql);


   while (rs.next()) {

    Cliente cli = new Cliente();

    cli.setCliCodigo(rs.getInt(1));
    cli.setCliNome(rs.getString(2));
    cli.setCliCpf(rs.getString(3));
    cli.setCliRg(rs.getString(4));
    cli.setCliFone(rs.getString(5));
    cli.setCliSexo(rs.getString(6));

    lista.add(cli);

   }


  } catch (Exception erro) {

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao listar " + erro.getMessage());

  }

  return lista;
 }

 public void alterarCliente(Cliente cli) {


  try {

   sql = "UPDATE cliente SET clinome=?,clicpf=?,clirg=?,clifone=?,clisexo=? WHERE clicodigo=?";

   pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
   pstm.setString(1, cli.getCliNome());
   pstm.setString(2, cli.getCliCpf());
   pstm.setString(3, cli.getCliRg());
   pstm.setString(4, cli.getCliFone());
   pstm.setString(5, cli.getCliSexo());
   pstm.setInt(6, cli.getCliCodigo());
   // Para Insert, Delete e Update usa-se: pstm.execute(). 
   // Para Select, usa-se: pstm.executeQuery();
   pstm.executeUpdate();

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados alterados com sucesso");

  } catch (Exception erro) {

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao alterar" + erro.getMessage());


  }
 }
 public void deletarCliente(Cliente cli) {


  try {

   sql = "DELETE FROM cliente WHERE clicodigo=?";

   pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
   pstm.setInt(1, cli.getCliCodigo());
   // Para Insert, Delete e Update usa-se: pstm.execute(). 
   // Para Select, usa-se: pstm.executeQuery();
   pstm.executeUpdate();

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Excluído com sucesso");

  } catch (Exception erro) {

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao excluir" + erro.getMessage());

  }
 }

}
```

Aqui está a classe do Cliente:

```
package model.bean;

public class Cliente {

    private Integer cliCodigo;
    private String cliNome;
    private String cliSexo;
    private String cliRg;
    private String cliCpf;
    private String cliFone;

    public Integer getCliCodigo() {
        return cliCodigo;
    }

    public void setCliCodigo(Integer cliCodigo) {
        this.cliCodigo = cliCodigo;
    }

    public String getCliNome() {
        return cliNome;
    }

    public void setCliNome(String cliNome) {
        this.cliNome = cliNome;
    }

    public String getCliSexo() {
        return cliSexo;
    }

    public void setCliSexo(String cliSexo) {
        this.cliSexo = cliSexo;
    }

    public String getCliRg() {
        return cliRg;
    }

    public void setCliRg(String cliRg) {
        this.cliRg = cliRg;
    }

    public String getCliCpf() {
        return cliCpf;
    }

    public void setCliCpf(String cliCpf) {
        this.cliCpf = cliCpf;
    }

    public String getCliFone() {
        return cliFone;
    }

    public void setCliFone(String cliFone) {
        this.cliFone = cliFone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return cliNome;
    }  
}
```

E aqui está o Servicos.java, onde eu faço o preenchimento do Combobox, com o seguinte método:

```
   public void preencherComboCliente(JComboBox comboCliente){

      ClienteDao cli = new ClienteDao();

      List<Cliente> listagem3 = cli.listarClientes();

       for(Cliente c:listagem3){


        comboCliente.addItem(c);

    }
}
```

Depois, chamo o método para preencher o combobox:

```
        servicos.preencherComboCliente(cbcliente);
```

Comment: Igo, o cliente Igor Brasil já vem selecionado quando você executa a aplicação?

Comment: Sim, ele já vem selecionado. Ah ;-; nossa, caí na real agora, realmente.
Mas como eu faria pra, além de pegar o selecionado, se eu mudar pro Adriano Tavares, mostrar apenas os dados do Adriano Tavares, ou seja, substituir os que estavam sendo mostrados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você quer é monitorar alterações no JCombobox(eu já até expliquei como se faz isso em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117903/28595) dê uma conferida lá). Basta adicionar um `ItemListener` ao seu combobox, e alterar o método `itemStateChanged`:

```
seuJCombo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                // 
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                  Cliente cli =  (Cliente) e.getItem();
                  txtareacliente.setText("Cliente: " +cli.getCliNome()+
                   "\n\nCPF: " +cli.getCliCpf()+
                   "\n\nRG: " +cli.getCliRg()+
                   "\n\nSexo: " +cli.getCliSexo()); 
                }
            }
       });
```

**Ressalva**: `txtareacliente` precisa ser ou uma campo da classe ou ser final para que o método anônimo reconheça seu campo de texto.

**Update**: para evitar exceções de cast caso seu combobox seja editável, teste a solução abaixo que, antes de entrar na seleção, checa se o item é do tipo `Pessoa`.

```
seuJCombo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                // 
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                  if (evt.getItem() instanceof Cliente) {
                    Cliente cli =  (Cliente) e.getItem();
                    txtareacliente.setText("Cliente: " +cli.getCliNome()+
                     "\n\nCPF: " +cli.getCliCpf()+
                     "\n\nRG: " +cli.getCliRg()+
                     "\n\nSexo: " +cli.getCliSexo()); 
                  }
               }
            }
       });
```

Comment: Parabéns Diego, é isso mesmo. Agora quando uma ação for executada na JComboBox, o listener instalado vai ouvir este evento e chamar o respectivo método que fará a alteração na JTextArea.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Diego. 
Eu vi algo muito parecido com isso em um vídeo, mas achei que não fosse necessário, muito obrigado mesmo!
Obrigado também Ingrid, por ter tentado me ajudar! Valeu.

Answer (score 2):

```
cli = (Cliente) this.cbcliente.getSelectedItem();
txtareacliente.setText("Cliente: " +cli.getCliNome()+
                       "\n\nCPF: " +cli.getCliCpf()+
                       "\n\nRG: " +cli.getCliRg()+
                       "\n\nSexo: " +cli.getCliSexo());    
txtareacliente.updateUI();
txtareacliente.revalidate();
txtareacliente.validate();
```

Comment: Não deu certo, ele continua a mostrar somente os dados do Igo Brasil, é como se ele só estivesse pegando o id do Igo Brasil no banco, sla..

Comment: Edita o post e insere mais partes do código, principalmente onde você cria e carrega o objeto cbcliente. Seu cliente não possui get's?

Comment: Possui, vou adicionar, um momento.

Comment: Pronto, adicionei.

Comment: Não encontrei nada de errado no carregamento dos dados na JComboBox. E aparentemente carrega corretamente os dados na combobox, visto que os nomes dos clientes aparecem corretamente. Poderia inserir a parte da sua view onde você exibe a combobox?

Comment: Sua resposta infelizmente não irá resolver o problema.

Comment: @DiegoF ele não está escutando o objeto combo, seria isso então?

Comment: O código da view já está no post, está logo abaixo da segunda imagem e também há outro código na view (na linha final do post), onde é "chamado" o método de preencher o ComboBox do cliente.

Comment: Ingrid, para isso existem os listeneres

Comment: Vamos imaginar um JTable com um alterar, digamos que eu clique em tal linha no JTable e ele automaticamente mostra (seta) os antigos dados do cliente para serem alterados, aí habilita o botão de alterar etc.
Seria a mesma lógica? Só que puxando os dados de um combobox.

Comment: @Igo veja minha resposta.