# Copiar a data de um JTextfield para um JDateChooser

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser

Atualmente eu espelho do `JDateChooser` para um `JTextField`, mas agora estou precisando espelhar de um `JTextField` para um `JDateChooser`. Como faço para copiar e converter uma data de um campo de texto para o JDateChooser?

Utilizo dessa maneira para mandar para o `JTextField`

```
    String dia = Integer.toString(JDateChooser1.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    String mes = Integer.toString(JDateChooser1.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    String year = Integer.toString(JDateChooser1.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR));
    String fecha = (dia + "/" + mes + "/" + year);
    EntradadadosData.setText(fecha);
```

Comment: Você testou a solução abaixo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o objetivo é converter a data do campo de texto, tente conforme abaixo:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(seutextfield.getText());

JDateChooser1.setDate(date);
```

Atente-se ao fato de que pegar entrada de usuário de um campo de texto e converter para data, sem nenhum tratamento ou restrição, vai ocasionar problemas que podem estourar em exceções de parse, se não puder ser garantido que os valores são realmente datas válidas. Caso o campo seja somente leitura, preenchido com data vindo de outro lugar onde seja garantido que a informação é realmente uma data, este problema pode ser descartado.

Comment: Desculpe Articuno, só pude ver agora. Deu certo sim, só tive q trocar o formato da data. Eu já havia pensado nessa possibilidade da pessoa enviar a data errada, mas fiz de uma maneira q isso não vai acontecer.

Comment: Estou com uma pequena duvida e gostaria de saber se vvc tem um post relacionado ao meu problema. Estou precisando agora de quando uma pessoa mudar um item de um combobox, ele limpar esse campo da data e mais alguns. para q a pessoa seja forçada a entrar com uma novada data.

Comment: @RafaelChaves sim, veja essa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117903/28595

Comment: perfeito! dois coelhos em uma cajadada. Vlw!